# Radiobutton value added to form

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and trying to make a small app for a friend. In this app there is a form people kan fill out and send. It contains information about name and adress etc.
The form works perfectly, but I cant find out how I can transfer the value from the checked radiobutton to the form.

package com.example.x_pand;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class Bestilling extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

        RadioGroup rg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bestilling);

    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
            if(r1.isChecked())

            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Afhentningsdag bliver næst kommende onsdag", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Afhentningsdag bliver næst kommende fredag", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }); 

    final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText addy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText emaile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    final EditText post = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    final EditText tlf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);

    Button mail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_form);
    mail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent email = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            /* Fill it with Data */
            email.setType("plain/text");
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test@mydomain.dk"});
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Bestilling til x-pand");
            email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                    "Navn: "+name.getText().toString()+'\n'+"Adresse: "+addy.getText().toString()+'\n'+"By: "+city.getText().toString()+ '\n'+"E-mail: "+emaile.getText().toString()+'\n'+"Tlf: "+tlf.getText().toString()+'\n'+"Post nr.: "+post.getText().toString()+'\n'+'\n'+"Bestilling til x-pand");

            /* Send it off to the Activity-Chooser */
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send mail..."));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


 }

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId); //UPDATE HERE
                if (r1.isChecked())

                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Afhentningsdag bliver næst kommende onsdag",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Afhentningsdag bliver næst kommende fredag",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
```

Comment: And how do you add it to the form?